# 5555=? Which letter goes in place of the question mark?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, calculation-puzzle

I have found this puzzle on the internet but I didn't get any answer yet, so help me out.

For rules see the given image:

[image: 1111=R,2222=T,3333=E,4444=N]

Here you can either give clues or may explain your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> 5555=Y

because

> the right-hand side is the last letter of the sum of all digits on the left-hand side. Thus 1111 -> FOU**R**, 2222 -> EIGH**T**, 3333 -> TWELV**E**, 4444 -> SIXTEE**N**, 5555 -> TWENT**Y**.